# Any side effect of using underscore wildcard in let command (i.e., let _ = ... in) in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, let

When using OCaml, I almost always use underscore wildcard in `let _ = exp`, especially when the result of `exp` is not important, but the computation inside it is. For example:

```
let _ = print_endline "abc" in
...
let _ = a := !a + 1 in
...
let _ = do_some_thing ... in
```

So, I just wonder if there is any side effect of extensively using `let _ = ...` ?

Answer (score 10):

The side effect is annoying bugs to track in your software in the future. The problem with `let _ =` is that it will silently ignore partial applications you intended to be total. Suppose you write the following:

```
let f a b = ...
let _ = f 3 4
```

And that in the future you add an argument to `f`:

```
let f a b c = ...
```

The expression `let _ = f 3 4` will still silently compile and your program will not invoke the function, leaving you wondering what is happening. It is much better to always let to `()` and use `ignore` when if you need to ignore a non unit result:

```
let () = ignore (f 3 4)
let () = print_endline "abc"
```

Using `let _ = ...` should be considered bad style.

Comment: *The side effect is annoying bugs to track in your software in the future.* I cannot agree more. What is the point of using a strongly typed language if one explicitly prevents the compiler to do anything useful with the types, as using the `let _ = …` sequences does?

Comment: It is not silently ignored: a warning 5 is printed.

Comment: Not with OCaml's default warning levels.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is absolutely no consequence to using `let _ =` extensively. The compiler does not add a name to the global environment since you didn't give one.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `let` is to bind values to identifiers. If you doing side-effects only it's its better to wrap it in a `begin .. end` block. In your case:

```fs
begin
    print_endline "abc";
    a := !a + 1;
    do_some_thing ();
end
```

Comment: That only works if the previous phrase is terminated by a `;;` marker.