# why the use of _ prevent having warnings

Tags: ocaml

I have the following code (it's a test so  it does nothing interesting)

```
let test k =
   let rec aux = function 
     |0 -> 0
     |z when z = 2 -> raise Exit 
     |_ -> aux (k-1) 
   in try let _ = aux k in true
   with Exit -> false
```

At the end there is the use of the syntax : `let _`, to me it's just a syntax when you don't have an idea of a name you can use to define your function.

Yet if I do the following :

```
let test k =
   let rec aux = function 
     |0 -> 0
     |z when z = 2 -> raise Exit 
     |_ -> aux (k-1) 
   in try let b = aux k in true
   with Exit -> false
```

I get a warning like : "variable b is unused", I don't understand why there is a difference between `let _` and `let b` ?

For example I know that when dealing with unit type it's common to use the syntax : `let ()`. Yet I don't have any warning when doing :

```
let b = print_int 2
```

even if I am not using :

```
let () = print_int 2
```

So what is particular with `let _` ?

Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any side effect of using underscore wildcard in let command (i.e., let \_ = ... in) in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048359/any-side-effect-of-using-underscore-wildcard-in-let-command-i-e-let-i)

Comment: Because that's how the language is designed? Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a convention, recognized by the compiler, to indicate that you're not going to use the result of a computation, e.g.,

```
let a = 5 + 6 in
()
```

will (or will not, depending on your warning settings) trigger the unused variable warning, since you clearly bound the result to a variable `a`, but not using it in the rest of your computation. In imperative languages it is quite common, to compute expressions for their side effects and ignore produced values if any. Since OCaml is a functional language, in which values are used to produce values, it usually an indicator of an error, when you forgot to use a bound variable.

Therefore, to explicitly tell the compiler that you're ignoring the value, you may start your variable with the underscore, e.g.,

```
let _unusued = 5 + 6 in 
()
```

You can just use a wild pattern `_` (which also starts with the underscore).

Answer (score 0):

You have a warning with your second code because you define the variable b containing a value and you do not use it after. 
The best use if you do not want to use the result of any expression is to discard its result using the 'let _ =' construct (it tells you want the expression to be evaluated, for potential side effects, but do not care to keep its result).

For the second part of your question, I think there are different rules related to the top loop, so the behaviours may not be comparable. In the first part, you define b inside a function and in the second part, you define b inside the top loop. In the top loop, you may define variables you will not use without getting a warning.